# Delete one element from a struct

Tags: c, struct

I have this struct of students

```
struct studentInfo
{
  int  intPersonalNumber;
  char charName[50];
  char charGender[15];
  char charStudyProgram[50];
  int  intAge;
  char charEmail[50];
};
```

Then I'm creating new struct elements with my dynamic struct array and then later on assigning them values.

```
student = realloc(student, (sizeof *student)*(elements+1));
```

So now I have multiple students as structs.

So my question is, how do i delete a struct element? For example how do i delete the first created student, `student[0]`.

Comment: move all other elements back to the start, and realloc the size down to adjust.

Comment: You probably are talking about "array members" and not "struct members". "struct member" would be `charName`, e.g.

Comment: deletions in a "vector" isn't as easy as in a linked list.

Comment: You can do one of three things:  (1) You can mark it as deleted, but leave it in the array.  That's fast, but you will have holes in your array (2) You can move everything past the element up one in the array, which in general will be very slow (and you'll have an extra unused element at the end), or (3) You can use a different data structure, such as a doubly-linked list, which supports efficient deletion (but not indexing).

Comment: @JensGustedt nice duplicate find!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : Arguably it is _simpler_ but it is certainly not efficient.

Comment: I am not sure about the "duplicate"; Transk gives `student[0]` only as an example whereas the "duplicate" is _specifically_ about removing the first element.  The answer can of course be generalised, bit it is by no means a given that Transk knows how to do that.  Also the question gives information about what he needs to achieve that might allow better solutions to be suggested such as marking for deletion/reuse or a more appropriate data structure.